# Spring: Allow missing database connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a project connecting to multiple databases (Oracle & SQLServer), some of which are not always mandatory nor available when starting the application - especially on a dev environment.

I'm looking for a way to allow the application to start without a database connection right-on. We only require a connection to these DB when doing specific tasks, which use a Staging Database requiring a specific network access not always available on dev.

Here, with our Oracle connection (which is the one being under a specific network) :

We had a configuration that allowed the application to start, but was throwing errors when running the Tests because of the erroneous HikariDataSource cast :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.bar.foo.repository.oracle",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "oracleEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "oracleTransactionManager"
)
public class OracleConfiguration {
private final Logger            log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Inject
private Environment             environment;

@Value("${spring.datasource.oracle.ddl-auto:none}")
private String hibernateddlAuto;

@Value("${spring.datasource.oracle.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect}")
private String hibernateDialect;

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.oracle")
public DataSourceProperties oracleDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.hikari")
public DataSource oracleDataSource() {
    HikariDataSource ds = (HikariDataSource) oracleDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    ds.setPoolName(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.oracle.poolName"));
    return ds;
}


@Bean
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oracleEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.bar.foo.domain.oracle");
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", hibernateddlAuto);
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    em.setDataSource(oracleDataSource());
    return em;
}

@Primary
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager oracleTransactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager


     = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
            oracleEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
}
```

I moved this configuration to extend HikariConfig as following :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.bar.foo.repository.oracle",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "oracleEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "oracleTransactionManager"
)
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.oracle")
public class OracleConfiguration extends HikariConfig{


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource oracleDataSource() {
      return new HikariDataSource(this);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oracleEntityManager() {
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  em.setPackagesToScan("com.bar.foo.domain.oracle");
  HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
  em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
  HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
      properties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", hibernateddlAuto);
      properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
  em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
  em.setDataSource(oracleDataSource());
  return em;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager oracleTransactionManager() {

  JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
    = new JpaTransactionManager();
  transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
    oracleEntityManager().getObject());
  return transactionManager;
}
```

Which does not start if the Oracle DB is unavailable.
Using an embedded DB would not suit our use case, as we do not always need this connection, and when we do we need specific data replicated from Production. 
Splitting this on multiple microservice/applications is also a no-go, as it would be a huge refacto, and does not really fit our use case (we aggregate data from multiple sources into a final one).

Is there a simple way to allow this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HikariCP` provides some really [nice configuration properties](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#infrequently-used) which may suit your needs. Specifically (the first one on that list) `initializationFailTimeout`:

> This property controls whether the pool will "fail fast" if the pool
>   cannot be seeded with an initial connection successfully...
>
> A value
>   less than zero will bypass any initial connection attempt, and the
>   pool will start immediately while trying to obtain connections in the
>   background. Consequently, later efforts to obtain a connection may
>   fail.

If you want to solve your problem this way, i.e. by hiding any initialization failures (by setting a negative `initializationFailTimeout` value), then you'll just have to make sure you have the right logic in case the DB is unaccesible/down when your getting a connection from the pool.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up finding the same property and answered right after you below :)
However, just setting this property less than zero didn't prevent the timeouts and increased the application start time because of it. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you sure it's just on initialization that it's happening? I wonder if Hibernate/JPA is trying to obtain an initial connection to do a validation or something. Maybe show your trace?

Comment: Here's the stacktrace, there are two separate timeouts : https://pastebin.com/reUxVanq

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Hibernate (i.e. `org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper`) and Spring JPA (i.e. `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup`) are both trying to use that `DataSource` on initialization. You're going to need to turn off any initialization for the dependers, like validation on the table, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after looking more at the HikariConfig class, I spotted the 
initializationFailTimeout which states

```
* @param initializationFailTimeout the number of milliseconds before the
*        pool initialization fails, or 0 to validate connection setup but continue with
*        pool start, or less than zero to skip all initialization checks and start the
*        pool without delay.
```

Setting it to zero or below allows the application to start, however it takes way much longer than it used to, and setting it below zero does not prevent it from waiting two connections timeouts.

I ended up also setting the connectionTimeout to the minimum 250ms on our dev configuration file, it seems to be working fine for now.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative solution is to set the following parameter:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Using that setting, I did not experience any slowness in application startup as I did when using the `initializationFailTimeout` setting.